# Sorting a parent relation by child relation in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a problem finding the correct query for my situation.
I have a User model, a Product model, a UserProduct model that has product_id and user_id and price, and a UserPromotion model which has a user_product_id and discount.
So I want to have them all nested and I want to have the highest discount (if there is one) for each user.
 So my query is like this:
`$promotions = User::whereHas('products')->with(['userProduct.product','userProduct.promotion'])->take(10)->get();`
I don't know how to get the highest discount promotion for each user.

Comment: could you post your User model so I can understand the relationships better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should reach the table user_promotions using leftJoin and then select the max discount:

```
$promotions = User::whereHas('products')
->with(['userProduct.product','userProduct.promotion'])
->leftJoin('user_products','user_products.user_id','users.id')
>leftjoin('user_promotions','user_promotions.user_product_id','user_products.id')
->select('users.*',DB::raw('MAX(discount)'))->take(10)->get();
```

please be careful about the tables names, they should match your tables in your db exactly